# can't install node/npm with either nvm or apt get install (wsl2 ubuntu)

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, wsl-2

I can't install node/npm with either nvm or apt get install (wsl2 ubuntu).  Here is what I tried first

```
$ code export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=http://nodejs.org/dist 
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
```

It installed nvm but when I did `nvm ls` I only got this (no versions listed)

```
->       system
iojs -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> N/A) (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
```

So I did  `~/.nvm` and tried `apt-get install -y nodejs` which seemed to work ...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  npm
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/122 kB of archives.
After this operation, 932 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 40014 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up nodejs (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/nodejs to provide /usr/bin/js (js) in auto mode
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Scanning processes...
Scanning candidates...
Scanning processor microcode...
Scanning linux images...

Failed to retrieve available kernel versions.

Failed to check for processor microcode upgrades.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

User sessions running outdated binaries:
 root @ /dev/pts/0: bash[9754,9845], sh[10875]
 root @ /dev/tty1: init[9752], wsltermd[9753]
 root @ /dev/tty2: bash[25], init[24]

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
```

Then I did `node -v` ...

```
bash: /usr/bin/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I am running on a brand new windows machine with win10 home.  I installed wsl2/ubuntu-22.04 and have been using it with no problem. So everything is fresh.  I am not behind any proxy.

I am pulling my hair out.  Can someone help me?

*EDIT:* I did `apt install nodejs npm` from a vscode wsl terminal and got a very long install which seemed successful.  Now when I run `npm i -g vite` I get ...

```
/usr/bin/node: 1: ELF: not found
/usr/bin/node: 2: : not found
/usr/bin/node: 4: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

so I'm losing even more hair.  By the way, I've been following The IT Crowd advice and rebooting often.

Answer (score 0):

I got node/npm installed by reverting to ubuntu 18.04, installing nvm, and doing `nvm install 'lts/*'`.
`nvm ls` still doesn't give any results so I'm surprised the install worked.  It's also a pain that I can't list the node versions.